# How to test for existance of a certain level in django messages

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to create a container `<div>` for my messages only if there is at least one message with level == `DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR.` (Then, I'll iterate through my messages and render the ones with error tags).

In pseudocode, something like this:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  {% if 'error' in message.tags %}
    <div id="error-container">
    {% break %} <!-- break doesn't exist -->
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What's the cleanest way of doing this in the template? I don't believe the templating language is expressive enough to break the loop through `messages` if it finds one with an error tag. Is there some way to use `firstof` or `|first` filter to create the `<div>` only on the first occurrence of an `error` message tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything built-in. I would suggest writing your own context processor or template tag/filter that extracts the ones with level ERROR. As a filter it might look like this:

```
@register.filter
def get_errors_only(messages):
    return [message for message in messages if 'error' in message.tags]
```

Now in the template you can just do:

```
{% with messages|get_errors_only as error_messages %}
  {% if error_messages %}
     ..
   {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Don't forget to load `{% load your_custom_templatetags %}` module in your template, and update your settings.py to use the extra templatetags as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best separation of business and presentation logic, and I'll be reusing the `get_errors_only` in a lot of other templates too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ifchanged` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged):

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'error' in message.tags %}
        {% ifchanged 1 %}
            <div id="error-container">
        {% endifchanged %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, filter `messages` in view function and pass it to template.

```
from itertools import islice

def view(request):
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', {
        'messages': islice((m for m in messages if 'error' in m.tags), 1),
    })
```